# Cannot convert from one model to another model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to save into two different tables. Taking data from Taxlaw and while saving, I save the same data in taxlawhistory table. So it's like copying data from one table to the other table and it's not working. The error I keep getting is

> Cannot convert from Model.TaxLaw to Model.TaxTableHisory

```
public  async Task<bool> SaveOrUpdate(IEnumerable<TaxLaw> obj)
        {


            using (var trans = _taxhistoryrepo.DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
              var lists = new List<TaxTableHistory>();

                foreach (var list in obj)
                {

                        lists.CompanyCode = list.CompanyCode;
                        lists.CummulativeAmount = list.CummulativeAmount;
                        lists.Percentage = list.Percentage;
                        lists.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        lists.ModifiedDate = list.ModifiedDate;
                        lists.Status = EntityStatus.Active;

                        _taxhistoryrepo.DbSetEntity.Add(lists);

                        await  _taxhistoryrepo.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                        await  Task.FromResult(_repository.SingleSave(obj));

                 }
                trans.Commit();
            }
            return true;

        }
```

Comment: you did not produce new variable the list variable is the same and your for loop actually do nothing because both variables are same

Comment: Can you give me an example please? i dont understand you

Comment: because you're adding list which is TaxLaw to TaxTableHistory, you need to create new TaxTableHistory , assign data to it and add created TaxTableHistory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

obj is of type

```
IEnumerable<TaxLaw>
```

so each iteam is

```
TaxLaw
```

Then you are trying to save into

```
_taxhistoryrepo
```

which I believe is using

```
TaxHistory
```

This part of code:

```
 foreach (var list in obj)
 {
   list.CompanyCode = list.CompanyCode;
   list.CummulativeAmount = list.CummulativeAmount;
   list.Percentage = list.Percentage;
   list.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
   list.ModifiedDate = list.ModifiedDate;
   list.Status = EntityStatus.Active;

   _taxhistoryrepo.DbSetEntity.Add(list);

   await  _taxhistoryrepo.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
   await  Task.FromResult(_repository.SingleSave(obj));
  }
```

Itarates through obj so the "list" is TaxLaw but here:

```
_taxhistoryrepo.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()
```

You adds TaxLaw type into TaxHistory table

I also belivie here is a typo as you are doing

```
list.CompanyCode = list.CompanyCode;
...
```

Which is basically setting same variable with same variable

What I suppose you wanted to achieve is:

```
 public  async Task<bool> SaveOrUpdate(IEnumerable<TaxLaw> obj)
    {
        using (var trans = _taxhistoryrepo.DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
          var lists = new List<TaxTableHistory>();

            foreach (var list in obj)
            {
                    var taxHistory = new TaxHistory();
                    taxHistory.CompanyCode = list.CompanyCode;
                    taxHistory.CummulativeAmount = list.CummulativeAmount;
                    taxHistory.Percentage = list.Percentage;
                    taxHistory.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    taxHistory.ModifiedDate = list.ModifiedDate;
                    taxHistory.Status = EntityStatus.Active;
                    //manually mapped TaxLaw into TaxHistory

                _taxhistoryrepo.DbSetEntity.Add(taxHistory); // save TaxHistory

              await  _taxhistoryrepo.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
               await  Task.FromResult(_repository.SingleSave(list)); //here save "list" not obj as you would save whole collection each iteration of the loop

             }
            trans.Commit();
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
public  async Task<bool> SaveOrUpdate(IEnumerable<TaxLaw> obj)
{
    using (var trans = _taxhistoryrepo.DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // var lists = new List<TaxTableHistory>();

        foreach (var taxLaw in obj)
        {
                var taxTableHistory = new TaxTableHistory();
                taxTableHistory.CompanyCode = taxLaw.CompanyCode;
                taxTableHistory.CummulativeAmount = taxLaw.CummulativeAmount;
                taxTableHistory.Percentage = taxLaw.Percentage;
                taxTableHistory.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                taxTableHistory.ModifiedDate = taxLaw.ModifiedDate;
                taxTableHistory.Status = EntityStatus.Active;

            _taxhistoryrepo.DbSetEntity.Add(taxTableHistory);

            await  _taxhistoryrepo.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            await  Task.FromResult(_repository.SingleSave(obj));
         }
        trans.Commit();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You were trying to add a Model.TaxLaw object to TaxTableHisory Repository because obj is a IEnumerable of of TaxLaw.

```
foreach (var list in obj)
_taxhistoryrepo.DbSetEntity.Add(list);
```

What you need is to create a new object of type TaxTableHisory and add that object

```
public async Task<bool> SaveOrUpdate(IEnumerable<TaxLaw> taxLawList)
    {
        using (var trans = _taxhistoryrepo.DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            foreach (var taxLaw in taxLawList)
            {
                var taxTableHisory = new TaxTableHisory();
                taxTableHisory.CompanyCode = taxLaw.CompanyCode;
                taxTableHisory.CummulativeAmount = taxLaw.CummulativeAmount;
                taxTableHisory.Percentage = taxLaw.Percentage;
                taxTableHisory.ModifiedDate = taxLaw.ModifiedDate;
                taxTableHisory.Status = EntityStatus.Active;

                _taxhistoryrepo.DbSetEntity.Add(taxTableHisory);
                await _taxhistoryrepo.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            trans.Commit();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Ps  : probably taxTableHisory is a type error of taxTableHistory

Answer (score 0):

Although the following code can resolve your issue, You can use [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) to map one object to another.

```
public  async Task<bool> SaveOrUpdate(IEnumerable<TaxLaw> obj)
    {
        using (var trans = _taxhistoryrepo.DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            foreach (var list in obj)
            {
                _taxhistoryrepo.DbSetEntity.Add(new TaxTableHistory {
                    CompanyCode = list.CompanyCode,
                    CummulativeAmount = list.CummulativeAmount,
                    Percentage = list.Percentage,
                    ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    ModifiedDate = list.ModifiedDate,
                    Status = EntityStatus.Active
            });

            await  _taxhistoryrepo.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            await  Task.FromResult(_repository.SingleSave(obj));
         }
         trans.Commit();
        }
        return true;
    }
```